# Integrated Windows Authentication with Chrome and FireFox

Tags: firefox, windows-authentication, google-chrome

I have a webapplication which uses claims based authentication. The STS is ADFS 2.0.
When I am in the intranet and use IE, IWA is used and no login dialog appears. When I am on the internet zone, the Forms based authentication of ADFS is used. Just what I want.

Chrome and FireFox are also working as expected when I am in the internet zone.
But when I am in the intranet zone, both come with a login dialog, instead of using IWA.
And supplying my credentials in that dialog does not work, it keeps repeating the dialog.

Any hints?

**UPDATE**: Did about an hour searching on the internet before I asked this question. But after asking it I did just another search giving the answer :-), matter of finding the correct keywords.
Here the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724377/mvc3-site-using-azure-acs-adfs-continually-prompts-for-credentials-when-using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did about an hour searching on the internet before I asked this question. But after asking it I did just another search giving the answer :-), matter of finding the correct keywords. Here the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724377/mvc3-site-using-azure-acs-adfs-continually-prompts-for-credentials-when-using

Answer (score 5):

Did you also look at the following setting for Firefox?

http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/

- Navigate to `about:config`
- Search for `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`
- Add your URIs. Separate multiple entries with commas.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Edited accordingly